# Mysql Group By not summing values

Tags: mysql, group-by

i have a table looking like that:

Datatypes = int

```
uid | fee1 | fee2 | fee3
1   | 0    | 5000 | 0
1   | 1000 | 0    | 0
```

I am trying to group the rows by uid so I have 1 row with summed values instead of 2.

My query:

```
Select uid, fee1, fee2, fee3, from payments GROUP BY uid.
```

The result:

```
uid | fee1 | fee2 | fee3
1   | 0    | 5000 | 0
```

Any Idea why the values dont sum ?

Comment: obviously there's no `sum()` within the query.

Comment: There is no sum because there are many users and i dont want the whole column to be summed

Answer (score -1):

```
select column1, sum(column2), ... from db group by preferred_column;
```

Even if you do not want to sum, there is no point in using group without sum. You shall get one row per group through this.